# GetChromeDataProcessor usage

Tags: pipelines

I am using the `GetChromeDataProcessor` processor as below. But I have a problem with the `GetChromeDataProcessor` inheritance. I am getting en error  "GetChromeDataProcessor is absolute so Please use another constructor instead". Does anyone have any idea what is causing the issue. I am using Sitecore 9.2.0.

```
public class RemoveDeleteIconPipeline : GetChromeDataProcessor
{        
    public string ReusableActionTeaserID = "{FF44910F-AEEE-48AE-811D-E4800F2B33CF}";
    public string ActionTeaserID = "{3032DF9D-9B9A-4CBF-BB8C-45BF6A0EAF8D}";

    public override void Process(GetChromeDataArgs args)
    {
        if (args.ChromeType == "rendering")
        {
            //Find the rendering and apply above code
            if (args.CustomData["renderingReference"] is RenderingReference renderingRef && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(renderingRef.Settings.Parameters))
            {
                var rmParams = WebUtil.ParseUrlParameters(renderingRef.Settings.Parameters);

                if (renderingRef.RenderingID.ToString() == ReusableActionTeaserID)
                {
                    foreach (var cmdItem in args.ChromeData.Commands)
                    {
                        if (cmdItem.Tooltip.Contains("Create or edit personalization for this component."))
                            cmdItem.Click = "";
                    }

                }

                if (renderingRef.RenderingID.ToString() == ActionTeaserID && rmParams["RemoveMoveandDelete"] == "true")
                {
                    foreach (var cmdItem in args.ChromeData.Commands)
                    {
                        if (cmdItem.Tooltip.Contains("Remove component."))
                        {
                            cmdItem.Icon = cmdItem.DisabledIcon;
                            cmdItem.Click = "";
                        }

                        if (cmdItem.Tooltip.Contains("Move component."))
                        {
                            cmdItem.Click = "";
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of problem are you trying to solve using this? Could you give some background about the requirements?

Comment: I am trying to disable  the Delete and Remove buttons for  the component . To disable webedit buttons i am using the above pipeline processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a constructor to your custom class since the class you are inheriting is an abstract class. If you don't need run any custom initialization code, just directly call the base class.

```
public class RemoveDeleteIconPipeline : GetChromeDataProcessor
{
    public RemoveDeleteIconPipeline(BaseClient client) : base(client)
    {
    }

    public override void Process(GetChromeDataArgs args)
    {
        if (args.ChromeType == "rendering")
        {
            ...
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: While loading the page , I got the below error even I defined the constructor."Inner Exception: Could not create instance of type: Metro.Foundation.Customization.Pipelines.ClientActionsChromeData.RemoveDeleteIconPipeline. No matching constructor was found"

Comment: Thanks its working fine . Yes we needs to define the constructor as well as we needs to add the resolve="true attribute" to the config file as below.
processor patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Editing.Pipelines.GetChromeData.GetOptimizationRenderingChromeData, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Editing']"
         type="Metro.Foundation.Customization.Pipelines.ClientActionsChromeData.RemoveDeleteIconPipeline, Metro.Foundation.Customization" />

Comment: It this solved your issue, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.